# How do I square Sin and Cos in Java?

Tags: java, math

I need help with this java exercise. The instructions are

> Write a program that uses Math.sin() and Math.cos() to check that the
>   value of sin<sup>2</sup>θ + cos<sup>2</sup>θ is approximately 1 for any θ entered as a
>   command-line argument. Just print the value. Why are the values not
>   always exactly 1?

My code so far (It is my first code so please no harsh judgement).

```
 public class math {
     public static void main(String[] args) {

         //Changes the data types from string to double
         double a = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
         double b = Double.parseDouble(args[1]);

         //Does the calculation math functions
         double s = 2*Math.sin(a);
         double c = 2*Math.cos(b);
         double target = .9998; // var for comparing if less than 1
         double answer = s + c;

         // Prints the answer and checks whether its less than 1
         System.out.println(answer < target);
         System.out.println(answer);
     }   
 }
```

I guessed on squaring the sin and cos. If anyone has quick suggestion on how to square sin and cos and if there is an error in my little program I will appreciate your help.

Comment: You are multiplying sin and cos by two. You should use Math.pow if you want to square it. An easier way is you multiply sin/cos with itself.

Comment: Additionally, you should convert the input to Radians using Math.toRadians() method, because Math trigonometric functions work with Radians values as parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are going to do is this. You got this wrong meaning of "sin^2θ". It's actual meaning is sin<sup>2</sup>θ. And same for cos. This is the code you are looking for.

```
double a = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);

//Does the calculation math functions
double s = Math.pow(Math.sin(a),2);
double c = Math.pow(Math.cos(b),2);
double target = .9998; // var for comparing if less than 1
double answer = s + c;

// Prints the answer and checks whether its less than 1
System.out.println(answer < target);
System.out.println(answer);
```

Answer (score 1):

you have one theta so: you need just args[0] and not args[1].
so `a=b` in your sample code.

squaring the sin and cos and adding:

Option 1:

```
double stheta = Math.sin(theta);
double ctheta = Math.cos(theta);
double answer = stheta*stheta + ctheta*ctheta;
```

Option 2:

```
double s2 = Math.pow(Math.sin(theta),2);
double c2 = Math.pow(Math.cos(theta),2);
double answer = s2 + c2;
```

working sample code:

```
package javaapplication1;

public class JavaApplication1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double theta = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
        double stheta = Math.sin(theta);
        double ctheta = Math.cos(theta);
        double answer = stheta*stheta + ctheta*ctheta;
        System.out.println(answer);
    }   
}
```

and see:
[Java - does double and float percision depend on the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668026/java-does-double-and-float-percision-depend-on-the-machine)
[Test Number For Maximum Precision In Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15710587/test-number-for-maximum-precision-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Floating point numbers are not exact representations.  Double precision 64 bit IEEE floating point representation only gives 17-18 digits, so you always compare differences to a tolerance.

I would recommend multiplying a number by itself for squaring over using `Math.pow()`.

Here's a [JUnit](http://junit.org) test that shows how I'd do it:

```
package math;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.Assert;

/**
 * Created by Michael
 * Creation date 6/25/2016.
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38024899/how-do-i-square-sin-and-cos-in-java
 */
public class MathTest {

    public static final double TOLERANCE = 1.0e-8;

    @Test
    public void testUnitCircleIdentity() {
        int n = 10;
        double t = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            double s = Math.sin(t);
            double c = Math.cos(t);
            double actual = s*s + c*c;
            Assert.assertEquals(1.0, actual, TOLERANCE);
            t += Math.PI/n;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Upvote for the answer which addresses the serious error in OP's approach to testing (approximate) equality.